# Getting the Physical Device Object name of a disk device

Tags: windows, kernel, setupapi, device-manager

I need to retrieve the "Physical Device Object name" of a disk device from a user mode application on Windows, as seen in Device Manager.

I have a solution now that involves a kernel driver that gets loaded and interrogated through IOCTLs. Once in kernel land, I have no trouble getting to that name. If possible, I would like to avoid using a kernel module.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get this using the Setup API functions.  Specifically I believe you can get this via SetupDiGetDeviceRegistryProperty and SPDRP_PHYSICAL_DEVICE_OBJECT_NAME.